# How to hide Firefox window PhpUnit test using (Selenium-WebDriver)

Tags: firefox, selenium-webdriver, phpunit

I want to execute a phpunit test using selenium webdriver but without the firefox window.

This is the setUp() function:

```
     public function setUp()
    {
    $capabilities = array(\WebDriverCapabilityType::BROWSER_NAME => 'firefox');
    $this->webDriver = RemoteWebDriver::create('http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',$capabilities);
    }
```

Any one can help me to resolve this?

Thank you for your help. B.Marwen

Comment: Try Headless browser if you don't want to see a window

Comment: Thank you for your response, i think i found a useful link:
 
https://www.sitepoint.com/using-the-selenium-web-driver-api-with-phpunit/